# how to store objectid in json file and fetch the query and execute in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I had JSON that contain JSON string . I want to replace JSON string to ObjectId

```
{
"_id" : "5fd484c39590020dc0dfb82a",
"eventId" : "5fd210952f4961e258437c9f"
}
```

I want to get the ObjectId like so,

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fd484c39590020dc0dfb82a"),
  "eventId" : ObjectId("5fd210952f4961e258437c9f")
}
```

```
db.collection('members').find().toArray({
"_id" : ObjectId("5fd484c39590020dc0dfb82a"),
  "eventId" : ObjectId("5fd210952f4961e258437c9f")
})
```

Is possible to convert the JSON string to ObjectId

Comment: But you are converting it to ObjectId in your last code block, are you not?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you might use mongoose, you can do it simply like that:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(object._id);
const eventId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(object.eventId);
```

If you are not using mongoose, an easier way would be to do this:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const _id = ObjectId(object._id);
const eventId = ObjectId(object.eventId);
```

Please note that object would be this:

```
const object = {
   "_id" : "5fd484c39590020dc0dfb82a",
   "eventId" : "5fd210952f4961e258437c9f" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

member = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('pass your string here');
console.log(user, typeof(member));
```